# Object moving up and down but not going left

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I take out the code in `void Update()`, the object will move left. Otherwise, the object will just move up and down in the same x-axis.

```
 public class movingRockUpScript : MonoBehaviour {
   public Rigidbody2D rgbody;
   public Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(-4, 0);
   Vector2 _start = new Vector2(0,-8);
   Vector2 _end = new Vector2(0,-3);
   public float _speed = 1f;
   // Start is called before the first frame update
   void Start()
   {
       rgbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
       rgbody.velocity = velocity;
       transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + Random.Range(1,5), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
   }

   // Update is called once per frame
   void Update()
   {
       float t = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, _speed) / _speed;
       transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(_start, _end, t);
   }
}
```

I tried putting `rgbody.velocity` in the `Update()` but that didn't change anything.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The code in the `Update` is assigning the position directly to whatever `_end` is, which is `new Vector2(0,-3);`, meaning it will just change the y. It will override any sort of velocity you are setting as you are directly setting position here.

Comment: The object will move up and down while moving left until it's offscreen which it will be destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to combine both velocity and your ping pong movement, it is possible, you would just have to set a single axis of movement for both. Instead of setting the transform directly and using `Vector2.Lerp`, use `Mathf.Lerp` on just the y component of the position instead.

```
public class movingRockUpScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public Rigidbody2D rgbody;
    public Vector2 velocity = new Vector2(-4, 0);
    Vector2 _start = new Vector2(0,-8);
    Vector2 _end = new Vector2(0,-3);
    public float _speed = 1f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rgbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rgbody.velocity = velocity;
        transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + Random.Range(1,5), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
    
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float t = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, _speed) / _speed;
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, Mathf.Lerp(_start.y, _end.y, t));
    }
}
```

Let me know if this is what you want as a desired outcome.